# Import and use 3rd Party Package with Webpack and Vue.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, vue.js

Good day,

I'm currently new in integration vue.js in webpack.

Basically, I'm trying to use a 3rd party package that I've already installed inside in my node_modules.

In this example, I installed a package called "Vuex Toast" (an alert for vue.js). [NPM Package here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuex-toast)

Here's my project structure.

```
.../js/main.build.js
.../src-modules/app.js (blank for now)
```

Normally, everytime I run webpack command, I generate my main.build.js

Can someone help me how to use that 3rd party package here?

Comment: You should import/require that module into your app.js to allow webpack to build your dependency tree.

Comment: can you provide an example based on this link. https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuex-toast? Basically, I just want to appear the basic alert provided by this package. And next time I can able to use other package if I find out how to incorporate other packages.

Comment: I have not used that module, however I think your confusing it with what `webpack` is supposed to be doing. It would be worth familiarising yourself with webpack first to gain an insight in how to use it.

Comment: But my actual concern is, to just incorporate it and being able to use that package. Because in installation, honestly, I don't know what to do with that in order to use the package in my project.

Comment: same thing with other packages as well. I can't use them because I have no idea how to in corporate them even I already installed them in my node_modules

Answer (score 1):

The idea of webpack (and bundlers in general) is that you `require` code and webpack bundles it for you.

In your `app.js` do the following:

```
const vuexToast = require('vuex-toast');
```

Now you can use it. Webpack will know to check your `node_modules/vuex-toast` folder.

Comment: Is that the only setup I need to do in order to show the alert from that package?

Comment: Of course not; that's how you get access to the package's code. To actually do something useful, follow the package's documentation: https://github.com/ktsn/vuex-toast#example

Comment: the problem is, I don't know how to follow the setup there. :/

Comment: @jsonGPPD is there a specific place in the `vuex-toast` documentation that's confusing? Maybe we can help clarify.

Comment: @Sidney Yeah, because I haven't tried adding 3rd party packages in vue.js. I really need a help in implementing it to my project with webpack. Calling the vuexToast is the first step, now I don't know what's the next step to implement the package.